# Is it possible to take birth in a different species(i.e supernatural beings)

Tags: karma, birth, supernatural-races

Atharva Veda 12.1.50.

Ye gandharvA apasarso ye chArAyAh kimidinah, pishAchAn sarvA rakshaushi, tAnasmad bhume yAvaya.

> Earth, drive away from us, Gandharvas, Apsaras, Arayas, Kimidins, Pishachas and all Rakshasas.

So can one(human) take birth as a Gandharvas, Apsaras, Arayas, Kimidins, Pishachas and all Rakshasas.

And what kind of karma(good or bad) should one do to attain such birth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to take birth in a different species(i.e supernatural beings).... So can one(human) take birth as a Gandharvas, Apsaras, Arayas, Kimidins, Pishachas and all Rakshasas.

Yes.

> And what kind of karma(good or bad) should one do to attain such birth.

This is exactly described in the Manusmriti:

> [Manu 12.39](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc202220.html) - I am now going to describe, briefly, in due order, those migratory states into which one falls through each quality from among these.

> 12.40 - Those partaking of ‘Sattva’ reach the state of the gods, those endowed with ‘Rajas,’ the state of men, and those characterised by ‘Tamas,’ the state of beasts; such is the threefold migratory state.

And [what follows](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc202223.html) are examples in each category:

> Cāraṇas, Suparṇas, hypocritical men, Rākṣasas, and Piśācas—represent the highest state among those partaking of the quality of ‘Tamas.’

> Gandharvas, Guhyakas, ‘Yakṣas,’ the attendants of the gods, and all the Apsaras, represent the high state among those partaking of ‘Rajas.’

> Ascetics and hermits, Brāhmaṇas, celestial beings, lunar asterisms, and Daityas represent the first state partaking of ‘Sattva.’

> Sacrificers, sages, gods, vedas, luminaries, years, Pitṛs and Sādhyas represent the second state partaking of ‘Sattva.’

> Brahmā, creators of the universe, Dharma, the Great One, Unmanifest,—these the wise ones describe as representing the best state partaking of ‘Sattva.’

Based on your guna, and the type of actions that you do based on a particular guna, you will be born into a particular species that partakes in the behavior of that guna.

So for example, if your consciousness and lifestyle is that of an insect, you will be born as an insect as the above passage describes. On the other hand, if you live a divine lifestyle, you will be born as a god (deva). If you live a materialistic lifestyle, you will be born as a gandharva or apsara. This is generally speaking, because other considerations like papa and punya (sin and merit) still factor in.

Comment: What is a divine lifestyle

Comment: @DarkKnight Sattvic lifestyle according to shastras.