# What is the way to born as Apsara in the next life?

Tags: apsaras

What spiritual and physical qualities should human person posses, to born as Apsara in the next life?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to take birth in a different species(i.e supernatural beings)](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/44542/is-it-possible-to-take-birth-in-a-different-speciesi-e-supernatural-beings). As the answer to the duplicate Q points out, your answer is available in Manusmṛti (12.39-51).